# Which one is better? "var" or "DataType"?

Tags: c#, variables, .net-4.0, c#-4.0

which one is better or maybe faster for declaring a variable?

```
var ds = new Class1();
```

OR

```
Class1 ds = new Class1();
```

I myself believe that second one should be faster coz compiler doesn't need to look for the type `Class1`, but some addins like `ReSharper` always notify me to change `Class1` to `var`.
Can anyone explain me why?

Comment: Note, this is not specific to 4.0.

Comment: yes yes... sorry... its from .Net3.5

Comment: Haven't we been over this like a million times?

Comment: Damnit, `var` exists since at least two years and some people still don't understand it... whoever tags a question about`var` with `dynamic-languages` should be banned from programming in .NET for not knowing crap.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They compile to the same IL, so neither will be faster. However, there can be a big difference in readability.

I *tend* to favour explicitly declaring the type of the variable, but use `var` if any of the following cases applies:

- I'm calling a constructor and the type name is long (particularly with generics)
- I'm using anonymous types
- The type name is *reasonably* long and the initialization expression is long, but still *very* clear as to what type it will return
- I want to emphasize the purpose of the code instead of how it achieves its result

As with many issues of readability, there's a vast range of opinions about where to use `var` - from "nowhere" to "everywhere". Note that you can change what ReSharper recommends for you in the options. (I seem to remember that by default it "recommends" both ways round - so really it's just making it easier for you to switch.)

A couple of answers have mentioned the number of keystrokes involved. I think this is the *worst* possible reason to favour `var`. I'm rarely, if ever, bottlenecked on typing speed. My coding speed is far more heavily dependent on my understanding of the problem domain, and on how clearly I can imagine the solution. I would far rather enter 2000 keystrokes but end up with an elegant design which is *actually* represented in 100 characters than type a mere 500 keystrokes for a less-readable 500-character design. Think about the time spent *reading* the code rather than the mechanics of typing.

Comment: In the case of LINQ expressions, I use `var` almost exclusively. Why should I bother to figure out what the type of the expression will be, and why should the reader care?

Comment: @Gabe: Most of the time, I entirely agree. Just every so often, it actually matters... but that's definitely the exception rather than the rule.

Answer (score 5):

They both compile to the same thing. When using `var`, you're simply letting the compiler infer the type at compile time. That may add a little bit of time to compilation (I haven't actually tested that part), but will have no impact at run-time.

The advantage of the former (which is what I prefer personally) is when you start to deal with long Type names:

```
var conn = new System.Data.SqlConnection(connString);
```

Is a lot less keystrokes and easier to read than:

```
System.Data.SqlConnection conn = new System.data.SqlConnection(connString);
```

In addition, without `var`, using Anonymous Types would be nearly impossible:

```
var someObj = new { Name = "Test", Saying = "Hello World!" };
```

There are definitely times that I prefer to use the full type name instead of `var` though. The most notable of which is when handling a return value of a method. If it is not clear from the name of the method what the type of the return value to be, I will explicitly define it. That reduces confusion in case anything changes down the road.

Comment: So, why `var` is recommanded?

Comment: @Dr TJ: It's less typing and there's less chance of you getting the type wrong if you change the definition later.

Comment: +10 for `change definition later`.

Answer (score 4):

This is merely type inference at compile time, so there is no performance cost. The "performance gain" is that it is faster to write `var` :)

Answer (score 2):

As a rule I would favour leaning against `var` when it isn't necessary (it is with anonymous types) and the type name isn't horribly complicated (`Dictionary<int, List<Class.InnerClass<HashSet<SomeOtherClass>>>` or such).

Every time I hear about this suggestion, checking out ReSharper slides a bit further down my to-do list.

Answer (score 2):

There is no performance difference -- the type of var is determined at compile time.

As to which one is better, it's a matter of preference.  Personally, I prefer var if the code clearly identifies the type of var.  Example:

```
// very much preferred
var o = new System.blah.blah.Class1()
```

However, if you have to think too much about the type, then like the type def:

```
  // I don't like this much because the return type isn't obvious
  var result = AMethodThatReturnsSomeKindOfValue()
```

Answer (score 1):

Go with whatever is more readable.  In your example, I think that the first example is more readable and has less duplication.  If you don't have the class name on the same line (because you are initializing the variable to the result of a method call for example), then I would use the type name declaration style to make it explicit to whoever is reading the code.